# Query pymongo with case insensitive text

Tags: python, regex, mongodb, pymongo

Following is how I query data from my mongodb using pymongo:

```
def is_philippine_facebook(self,facebook_user):
        is_philippine = False
        db_server = self.ConfigSectionMap('db_server')
        database_name = db_server['database']
        db = self.client[database_name]
        cursor = db[collection_name].find({
                'isPhilippine':True,
                'facebook_user': re.compile('@'+facebook_user, re.IGNORECASE)
            })
        for document in cursor:
            if document is not None:
                is_philippine = True
                break
        return is_philippine
```

In fact, I want to query records having a certain `facebook_user` with `case insensitive` option. However, the query returns many incorrect results.
For example, if `facebook_user` is `WWF`, records with `WWF_XYZ` will be returned.

How can I fix this?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like you want a word boundary `\b`

```
'facebook_user': re.compile('@'+ facebook_user +'\\b', re.IGNORECASE)
```

So if you supply `WWF` or `wwf` then it only matches up to the end of the "word" and not beyond it.

As a note, case insensitive searches an searches not anchored with the caret `^` to the beginning of the string require a full collection scan and are not very efficient.

If matching to the beginning of a string you should use the caret, and you should probably normalize case as a document property for searching so you do not need the "case insensitive" option either. These two things are required for an index to be used on a search. See [`$regex`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/regex/) in the documentation

Comment: Exactly what I want. Yep, I should normalize the text data when inserting to the mongodb.

Answer (score 2):

Use the following fix:

```
re.compile(r'@{0}\b'.format(facebook_user), re.IGNORECASE)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/XZ9WGp/2).

**Pattern details**:

- `@WWF` - a literal `@WWF`
- `\b` - a word boundary (requires a char other than letter, digit or `_`, or end of string after `@WWF`)

If a `facebook_user` may contain special chars, you need to use

```
re.compile(r'(?<!\w)@{0}(?!\w)'.format(re.escape(facebook_user)), re.IGNORECASE)
```

However, the `facebook_user` seems to only contain word chars, so a word boundary should really suffice in this case.